# move_uploded_file issue

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how the file upload system works in PHP. My code is:

```
if(isset($_FILES['profile_pic'])){
    $allowed_ext= array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
    $file_name = $_FILES['profile_pic']['name'];
    $file_ext = strtolower(end (explode('.',$file_name)));
    $file_size = $_FILES['profile_pic']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['profile_pic']['tmp_name'];
    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === false || $file_size > 2000000){
        $display_block = 'display:block !important';
        $pic_errors ='<p>*  File format JPG, JPEG, GIF or PNG</p> <p>*  Smaller 1Mb</p>';
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '/members/');
        echo 'uploaded..';
    }
}//if(isset($_FILES['profile_pic']))
```

with permissions everything seems to be fine.

The error I get is:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/members/) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /home/a6671212/public_html/settings.php on line 116

How do I fix this error?

THANKS to everyone..

as i understood i had 2 issues..

1. as @Prisoner wrote..
   move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '/members/'); - i didn't wrote the file name after /members/
2. as @Ketan Patel wrote,

the function should be changed to another format, if i may say so..

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "/members/$file_name"); - double quotes...

It Worked!!!!!!!! Thank YOUUU!!!

Comment: Does the members directory exist? Do you have permission to upload there?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623622/issue-with-move-uploaded-file

Comment: That error is fairly self explanatory

Comment: i don;t understand the error guys, sorry, i am new to php..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define a filename, so something like:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'members/filename.ext');
```

or, in your case:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'members/'.$file_name);
```

Also, is /members/ a directory (in the root of your filesystem)? If not, use a relative or absolute path to the members directory. Edit: Judging by the error, I'm guessing /members/ is a directory, so this should work fine:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '/members/'.$file_name);
```

Don't forget to also check for the file existence first otherwise `move_uploaded_file` will overwrite the old file.

Comment: yes, members it is a directory..

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '/members/'.$file_name);

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/members/very-angry-little-soldier.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a6671212/public_html/settings.php on line 116

folder members DOES exists..

Comment: it may be a directory, but is it in your ROOT filesystem. Please read up on paths: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

The function [`move_upload_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) works like the unix command `mv`. You have to specify the target file path.

Change your code line to this and it should work:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, './members/' . $file_name);
```

Comment: `+` is not the correct concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '/members/');
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'members/' . $filename);
```

( Remove first slash and add filename )

Comment: you need to use . for concatenation not +

Comment: no worries, didn't want you getting a downvote for an otherwise correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you use this function

```
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '/members/' . $fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '/members/');
in
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'members/' + $filename);

And make sure to set permission right with chamod. 
chmod -R 0755 members. Also make sure that you're app have access at $file_temp location and read/write permision